# Display picture in front end with category

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I tried to show the picture based on category, in each category i want to show 10 picture so i make add this code in my controller:

> public function landing()
> {
> $numbers = Number::get();
> $portfolios = Portfolio::get();
>
> ```
> $fabrikasiPortfolios = Portfolio::where('category', 'fabrikasi')
>     ->latest()
>     ->take(10)
>     ->get();
>
> $konstruksiPortfolios = Portfolio::where('category', 'konstruksi')
>     ->latest()
>     ->take(10)
>     ->get();
>
> $repairPortfolios = Portfolio::where('category', 'repair')
>     ->latest()
>     ->take(10)
>     ->get();
>
> $lainnyaPortfolios = Portfolio::where('category', 'lainnya')
>     ->latest()
>     ->take(10)
>     ->get();
>
>     $testimonials = Testimonial::get();
>     $clients = Client::get();
>      return view("landing/landing",  compact('numbers', 'portfolios', 'testimonials', 'clients', 'fabrikasiPortfolios',
> ```
>
> 'konstruksiPortfolios', 'repairPortfolios', 'lainnyaPortfolios'));
> }

this take(10) doesnt work. work only in the all category ="*"
my blade:

> ```
>       <ul class="portfolio-flters" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
>         <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li>
>         <li data-filter=".filter-fabrication">Fabrikasi</li>
>         <li data-filter=".filter-construction">Konstruksi</li>
>         <li data-filter=".filter-repairs">Repair</li>
>         <li data-filter=".filter-design">Lainnya</li>
>       </ul>
> ```
>
> @foreach($portfolios as $portfolio)   @if($portfolio->category ===
> 'fabrication')
> @if($loop->iteration <= 10)
>
>
> image }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
>
> {{ $portfolio->category }}-->
> {{ $portfolio->title }}
>
> -->
> image }}" title="{{ $portfolio->title }}"
> data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-remodeling" class="glightbox
> preview-link">
>
>
>
> @endif
> @elseif($portfolio->category === 'construction')
> @if($loop->iteration <= 10)
>
>
> image }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
>
> {{ $portfolio->category }}-->
> {{ $portfolio->title }}-->
> image }}" title="{{ $portfolio->title }}"
> data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-remodeling" class="glightbox
> preview-link">
>
>
>
> @endif
> @elseif($portfolio->category === 'repair')
> @if($loop->iteration <= 10)
>
>
> image }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
>
> image }}" title="{{ $portfolio->title }}"
> data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-remodeling" class="glightbox
> preview-link">
>
>
>
> @endif
> @else
> @if($loop->iteration <= 10)
>
>
> image }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
>
> {{ $portfolio->category }}-->
> {{ $portfolio->title }}-->
> image }}" title="{{ $portfolio->title }}"
> data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-remodeling" class="glightbox
> preview-link">
>
>
>
> @endif
> @endif @endforeach

after i post the 11th picture, the picture wont show even in fabrikasi category only 3 picture posted. how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($fabrikasiPortfolios as $portfolio)
    <img src="{{ $portfolio->image }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    {{ $portfolio->category }} --> {{ $portfolio->title }}
    <a href="{{ $portfolio->image }}" title="{{ $portfolio->title }}" data-gallery="portfolio-gallery-remodeling" class="glightbox preview-link"></a>
@endforeach

@foreach($konstruksiPortfolios as $portfolio)
@endforeach
```

Similar for all

Comment: but how for this line: <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li>, the picture show more than 10